# Tyring to set UIImage from different fiew via delegation

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller with a UIImage that will be sent to a service. I'm trying to load this image from another view so I'm using delegation. However I cant seem to understand why it will not work. I set some messages to print in the console and I see them right before the call to the method but its not setting the variables and I'm not sure why.

The view are linked via a navigation controller and to return I use popViewController and to go to the other view controller I use a simple show segue from the button. The "confirmation" of the selected image is done with a button that is supposed to send the image to the previous view controller.

This is the main controller with the UIImage I want to set from another view:

```swift
import UIKit

class MainNewPost: UIViewController{
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
        return.lightContent
    }
    
    var imageForUpload: UIImage?
    var isImageSelected: Bool = false
    
    @IBOutlet weak var newPostBox: TVUIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var newPost: UIButton!
    
    @IBAction func sendNewPost(_ sender: Any) {
        
        var imageId = ""
        
        if isImageSelected {
            imageId = UUID().uuidString
            ImageWS.sendIamge(imageId: imageId, image: imageForUpload!, {()}, error: {(errorMessate) in
                print(errorMessate)
            })
        }
        
        
        if (newPostBox.text!.isEmpty) {
            Util.showMessage(controller: self, message: "Ingrese un texto", seconds: 5)
        } else {
            PostWS.newPost({() in
                Util.showMessage(controller: self, message: "Enviaste un mensaje!", seconds: 3.0)
                
            }, img: imageId, postBody: newPostBox.text!, personId: PersonBE.shared!.personId, posterName: PersonBE.shared!.displayName, error: {(errorMessage) in print(errorMessage)})
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   }
        
}

extension MainNewPost: NewPostDelegate {

// This is not executing. I'm calling it since I see the console message by the flag and image dont get set
    func selectedImage(_ image: UIImage, _ isImageSelected: Bool) {
        self.imageForUpload = image
        self.isImageSelected = isImageSelected
    }
}
```

This is the view controller where I select the image:

```swift
import UIKit

protocol NewPostDelegate {
    func selectedImage(_ image: UIImage, _ isImageSelected: Bool)
}

class imageSelectViewController: UIViewController {

    var postDelegate: NewPostDelegate?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var imagePicker: ImagePicker!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
     
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.imagePicker = ImagePicker(presentationController: self, delegate: self)
    }

    @IBAction func showImagePicker(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.imagePicker.present(from: sender)
    }
    
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
        return.lightContent
    }
    
    @IBAction  func clickBtnBack(_ sender: Any){
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
    @IBAction func selectImage(_ sender: Any) {
// I see this message printed in the console
// This button is suposed to send the selected image to the previous view controller
        print("In selectImage button")
        self.postDelegate?.selectedImage(imageView.image!, true)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
}

extension imageSelectViewController: ImagePickerDelegate {

    func didSelect(image: UIImage?) {
// I see this message printed in the console
        print("In didSelect delegate method")
        self.imageView.image = image
        self.postDelegate?.selectedImage(image!, true)
    }    
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `var postDelegate: NewPostDelegate?` in your `imageSelectViewController` instance remains `nil`. Which means that even if you're calling a delegate method, there is no delegate specified itself.

In order to fix it you should assign your `MainNewPost` instance reference to `var postDelegate: NewPostDelegate?` of your destination `imageSelectViewController` while preparing for segue.